# Proof that the inverse of a growing matrix whose elements converge to the identity matrix converges to the identity matrix

Tags: matrices, limits, inverse

Consider a matrix of the form $I+A$, where $I$ is an identity matrix of size $n$ and $A$ is a matrix of size $n$ where each element is less that $\tfrac{1}{n} B $ in absolute value ($B>0$). I want to prove that the elements of the inverse $(I+A)^{-1}$ converge to the elements of the identity matrix of size $n$ as $n \to \infty$. The bound $B$ does not change as the matrix size increases. I can assume that $A$ is symmetric positive definite if that helps. I can't assume that the size of the elements converge to zero at a rate faster than $\tfrac{1}{n}$. This result seemed to be true in simulations I ran, but I have been stuck on coming up with a proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix with each element equal to $-1/n$, then $I+A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks! I can assume that $A$ is symmetric positive definite, so this this rules out $A_{ij}=-\tfrac{1}{n}$ for all $i$ and $j$. This is helpful because it suggests that if the result is true, the requirement that $A$ is symmetric positive definite must be used somewhere in the proof. Any ideas for whether the result is true when $A$ is symmetric positive definite?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a true assertion when $B<1$, and here is a possible proof: each individual matrix $A^k$ tends to the zero matrix as $n\to\infty$, and we have the series
$$
(I+A)^{-1} = I - A + A^2 - A^3 + A^4 - \cdots.
$$
One would have to justify taking the limit term by term as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I tried working with the Nuemann series as you suggested but couldn't make it work. I tried coming up with a bound on the norm of the remainder of the series $-A + A^2 - A^3 - ... $. I could come up with a bound if the norm was submultiplicative based on the sum of a geometric series, but I wasn't able to find a submultiplicative norm where $||A|| < 1$, which is necessary for the series to converge. Alternative, $||A|| < 1$ when the norm is the max element of the matrix, but this norm is not submultiplicative, so I wasn't able to come up with an argument for a bound on the remainder.